# How can I keep excel from "Not Responding", when running my refresh macro?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]Through research, it seemed all I needed to do was use this? But my screen still bugs out while refreshing. I am just wanting the screen to not change or do anything at all when running this macro.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Here is just a small piece of my code that runs in this macro for reference:

```
Sub Refresh_Data()

Box.Show

Application.Cursor = xlWait
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("IOM Denial.xlsm").RefreshAll
Workbooks("IOM Denial.xlsm").Worksheets("Home").Activate

Application.Cursor = xlDefault
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Unload Box

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to So. Add `DoEvents` right after `Workbooks("IOM Denial.xlsm").RefreshAll`. Also, if there is any code in any event, you should add `Application.EnableEvents=False` (true after finished).

Comment: What is `box` just a form showing it's working?  Or is there anything going on in there?

Comment: The box is just a little box that comes up with a picture inside.

Comment: How does it work, moving the code to the form and then calling, so `box.RefreshAllTables` for example?

Comment: There is no code on the form. It's just a simple box with an image in it.

Comment: @zbreeden007   Ok, so add the code above to the form and call from the form, rather than show form then have code after.  So have this as a `public Sub Refresh_Data()` in the form, and call like `box.show:box.Refresh_data:unload box`

Comment: Screen still goes blank when refreshing

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the box in a modal form, Excel is waiting for a response from you before proceeding any further than `Box.Show`. If you close the `Box` using the little cross, your code should continue to run.

You can fix this in your code by changing the line to

```
Box.Show False '<-- runs non-modal
```

Information from Microsfot here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/showmodal-property

Comment: No, my code runs while the box is showing. I'm just talking about the screen freezing and going all white when the queries are refreshing. The problem is because my query takes a while but I'm wondering if there is a visual way around it.